# How can I have the same latex font of this book?

Tags: fonts, templates, thesis, books

I'm writing my manuscript for my thesis and this the package that I'm using for the fonts :

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
```

I was reading a physical book and I want to know which type of font the author is using for his template.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: you should not be using `ae` package this century and certainly loading `ae` and `lmodern` at the sane time can not work, they can not both set the default document font.

Comment: The name of your book is: Introduction to Microfluidics Di Patrick Tabeling.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I wonder whether time is  really sane? :-)

Comment: @Bernard the current time, I have my doubts :(